# In Unity how do I make a button call everything suscribed to the "onEndEdit" event of an InputField?

Tags: unity, c#

How do I make a method (that is going to be called every time that a button is pressed) to call everything subscribed to the "onEndEdit" event of an InputField?

I expected something like this:

```
public class DoneButtonInputField : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private InputField inputField;

    public void ClickDoneButton()
    {
        inputField.onEndEdit();
    }
}
```

But it does not work and I do not know how to search for the answer (probably by vocabulary lack).

Comment: Have you tried `inputField.onEndEdit.Invoke();`? I think it's the way to go in order to manually call the callbacks to the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way:

```
inputField.onEndEdit.Invoke(inputField.text);
```

I'm trying to do it because the InputField component does not allow you to have a button to finish the editing of the text, so I'm adding it. That's why I want to call the event when the button is pressed, which means that the edit is finished.